# How to version control modules.xml?

Tags: android, git, android-studio, intellij-idea, version-control

I started cloning an Android project from my Git server and while initially opening the project Android Studio gave me an error: "Cannot load module myProject" and asks me to remove it.

After the removal Git then is already showing me a change made to the modules.xml file:

```
<module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/old_project_name.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/old_project_name.iml" />
```

got changed to

```
<module fileurl="file://$PROJECT_DIR$/new_project_name.iml" filepath="$PROJECT_DIR$/new_project_name.iml" />
```

That's caused by the different project name (Android Studio / IntelliJ can't find the path listed in modules.xml) and is therefore hard to put under version control where users may have different names for their local clone of the project.

There already is a [post about making this project name user-independent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34927251/replace-project-name-with-variable-in-android-studio-modules-xml), coming to no results.

The [IntelliJ IDEA help site](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/2016.3/project.html) states:

> The .idea directory contains a set of configuration files (.xml). Each file contains only a portion of configuration data pertaining to a certain functional area which is reflected in the name of a file, for example, compiler.xml, encodings.xml, modules.xml.
>
> Almost all of the files contain information core to the project itself, such as names and locations of its component modules, compiler settings, etc. Thus, these files may (and should) be kept under version control.

Another [answer on a question about version control for the .idea/ directory](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26336926/7162651) is about configuring Gradle / Maven to substitute the IDEA project files.

How is this done?

Is there a way to achieve a user-independent modules.xml?

**EDIT:** Adding the file to .gitignore appears to work, the IDE will generate it.

Comment: Can't you implement it in `dependencies` in the **app-gradle**?

Comment: I'm not that into gradle, but I'll try it out ;)

Comment: I don't know how to implement modules, but I added a lot of Git projects to my apps through gradle :)

Comment: Is it possible to just .gitignore that certain file in your .idea folder ?

Comment: @SoumyaKumar I've already tried that, but after rechecking it suddenly worked, the IDE seems to generate it just fine, thanks :)

Comment: Maybe this post can also help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35705698/error-loading-project-in-android-studio-cannot-load-modules

Comment: @Marina-MSFT I don't synchronize the .iml files with git, so after deleting the modules it built the project. 
But then modules.xml began to change and that was my actual problem.

Comment: So for android studio, you can’t control modules.xml file as user-independent. You can use .gitignore to ignore the file.